# Redis setting TTL on hSet Keys

Tags: caching, redis, redis-cli

I am on an dead end with redis cache. I want to set an TTL on the initiation of a key. The key will be set by hSet($hash, $key, $data)

```
expire($key, '3600')
```

does not seem to work. Is there an hExpire() method?

Comment: short answer: _no_. long answer: _no, you can't_.

Comment: 2024-03-31: Redis started implementing hash field expiration, and it's planned for an upcoming release. https://github.com/redis/redis/pull/13172

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Redis supports expiration only on KEY level. It does not support expiration on inner element(s) of any data structure, let alone hash.

**Answer:**

1. No. There is no `hExpire` method/command in Redis.
2. You're trying expire an inner element in a hash. This is not possible in Redis.

**Update:**

You can expire a whole data structure (a.k.a. a key).

One of the command to expire key is `EXPIRE key seconds`.

Assuming you are using phpredis, your method call can be `setTimeout($hash, 3600)`.

Comment: Can I expire or set a TTL for the hash? Tomasz says I can put a TTL on the hash itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the TTL on the `$hash` itself as you can't expire individual keys of a hash.

Comment: Which method is that? How can I do so?

Comment: @Isengo He meant TTL on the key itself using https://redis.io/commands/expire. You can't expire a hash, but you can expire each key.

Comment: @sazzad Why does Redis not support the EX parameter for HSET like it does for SET ? It is constraining to have to make a second EXPIRE command

Answer (score -2):

You can try TairHash, which is a redis module, similar to redis hash, but you can set expire and version for the field: https://github.com/alibaba/TairHash